# c++ Winforms TextBox error

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

I'm a beginner in c++, and I'm trying to use winforms in my win32 program. This is the code:

```
System::windows::Forms::Label hwl = (gcnew System::windows::Forms::Label());
hwl->Text = L"Hello world";
```

I have this error in dev C++:

> C:\Users\Max.Ana-PC\Documents\c++\win32 hello world\main.cpp  In
>   function 'int WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)':
>   57    2   C:\Users\Max.Ana-PC\Documents\c++\win32 hello
>   world\main.cpp    [Error] 'System' has not been declared
>   57    32  C:\Users\Max.Ana-PC\Documents\c++\win32 hello
>   world\main.cpp    [Error] expected ';' before 'hwl'
>   58    2   C:\Users\Max.Ana-PC\Documents\c++\win32 hello
>   world\main.cpp    [Error] 'hwl' was not declared in this scope
>   28        C:\Users\Max.Ana-PC\Documents\c++\win32 hello
>   world\Makefile.win    recipe for target 'main.o' failed

Am I using the wrong type (most likely cause), or missing a `#include <...>`? I can't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using C++ but rather C++/CLI.

If the program was created through the "Win32 project" wizard in Visual Studio, right-click on the project's properties, look under something called "Configuration Properties / General" or similar, and check if "Common Language Runtime Support" is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my VS (ultimate and express) broke down. I'm limited to dev c++ so is there a way to do this in dev c++?

Comment: I don't think so unless someone has created a wrapper that lets you call managed code (that would be a separate question). C++/CLI is a different language from C++.